# How to compile linux application into win *.exe file

Tags: python, linux, windows, ubuntu, exe

I have python program that I've been writing on Ubuntu. For some reasons I could not properly installed on windows few libraries that I used, there are some problems I can't solve in libraries. I used PyInstaller to build run file in Ubuntu. And it is works perfectly. But now I faced a problem, I need to run this application on windows. And it specifically need to be an exe file, so I would not need to install ubuntu vmware on every PC in which I use this app. So is there any solution to compile/convert run file to exe?

Comment: You could do the opposite. Run Windows in a virtual machine on your Ubuntu development machine, to create `*.exe` files.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on packages you used in you project. Some  of them (binaries) not portable. In common case, try [py2exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Py2exe)

Answer (score -1):

if you can't get the python to run on windows a packaged exe version is impossible.